# MongoDB exiting with code 14 and mongo shell connection refused

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have installed mongodb and tried to start it
`sudo systemctl start mongod`
but i just get an error.

`systemctl status mongod.service` gives:

```
    ● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server 
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2023-12-12 09:25:39 UTC; 6min ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 31904 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=14)
  Process: 31902 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 31901 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 31899 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 13891 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 
Dec 12 09:25:39 test systemd[1]: Starting MongoDB Database Server...
Dec 12 09:25:39 test mongod[31904]: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
Dec 12 09:25:39 test mongod[31904]: forked process: 31907
Dec 12 09:25:39 test mongod[31904]: ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 14
Dec 12 09:25:39 test mongod[31904]: To see additional information in this output, start without the "--fork" option.
Dec 12 09:25:39 test systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process exited, code=exited status=14
Dec 12 09:25:39 test systemd[1]: Failed to start MongoDB Database Server.
Dec 12 09:25:39 test systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
Dec 12 09:25:39 test systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
```

and when i try and acess the mongo shell with `mongo`

```
    MongoDB shell version v4.2.25
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2023-12-12T09:32:52.738+0000 E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:353:17
@(connect):2:6
2023-12-12T09:32:52.740+0000 F  -        [main] exception: connect failed
2023-12-12T09:32:52.740+0000 E  -        [main] exiting with code 1
```

I have tried removing the mongod.lock file, i have changed the ownership and permissions of files. Nothing has worked.
I have also tried uninstalling mongo and reinstalling but this has not worked either. what should I do?

UPDATE:
I have checked the `mongod.log`

```
2023-12-12T09:22:42.641+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2023-12-12T09:22:42.641+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
2023-12-12T09:25:39.922+0000 I  CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2023-12-12T09:25:39.927+0000 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2023-12-12T09:25:39.936+0000 W  ASIO     [main] No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup
2023-12-12T09:25:39.938+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=31907 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongo 64-bit host=test
2023-12-12T09:25:39.938+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.25
2023-12-12T09:25:39.938+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 41b59c2bfb5121e66f18cc3ef40055a1b5fb6c2e
2023-12-12T09:25:39.938+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
2023-12-12T09:25:39.938+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2023-12-12T09:25:39.938+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2023-12-12T09:25:39.938+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2023-12-12T09:25:39.938+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: rhel70
2023-12-12T09:25:39.938+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2023-12-12T09:25:39.938+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2023-12-12T09:25:39.938+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27017 }, processManagement: { fork: true, pidFilePath: "/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid", timeZoneInfo: "/usr/share/zoneinfo" }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongo", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
2023-12-12T09:25:39.939+0000 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Unable to read the storage engine metadata file: FileNotOpen: Failed to read metadata from /var/lib/mongo/storage.bson
2023-12-12T09:25:39.939+0000 F  -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28661 at src/mongo/db/storage/storage_engine_metadata.cpp 89
2023-12-12T09:25:39.939+0000 F  -        [initandlisten] \n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n
```

I'm not quite sure how to interpret this, does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Have a look at the logfile, typically at `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`